# Adding primary key in target database through AWS glue job

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am doing some POC's in AWS glue. Now I am able to parse excel uploaded in S3 and stored into RDS instance. I have mapped the columns in excel to table columns. But there is no primary key in the resultant table in RDS instance. Can I add a new column as primary key (incremental values) in the RDS table for further processing. There is no such unique value in the uploaded excel. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It depends. What do you intend to use the primary key for. Can it be a random value. Also are u creating the rds table before hand or is your intention to have glue create it on load.

Comment: My intention is to create table on load by glue. The primary key should be like what we have in postgres or like in any other SQL database, auto incrementing. Also the files will be uploaded to S3 one after the other, or day by day.

Comment: You are better of defining your table in your rds before hand and having an auto incrementing column defined there and just let glue upload the columns form the excel sheet. If you want to avoid that,yYou will need to add a logic in your glue script, to create a column for the dynamic frame that will set a unique value for each and every row

Comment: Yes... I tried with that and was successful...Thanks for your update.